# how to test laravel page from client PC

Tags: ubuntu, laravel

I have install laravel in ubuntu server.
i.e. server ip : 10.111.12.11 (host name = dog)

i run `php artisan serve`
and return

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
```

then i go to my browser and type

```
http://10.11.12.11:8000

return no page found.
```

i try netsat in server.
port 8000 listen by /usr/bin/php5.
that i think correct.

i try manually go to /laravel-folder/public/

it return the hello page. that is correct.

how to solve the the case, to test laravel page from client pc.
because im using ssh to remote from windows environment.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the server IP "10.111.12.11", or is it "10.11.12.11"?

Answer (score 1):

The serve command of artisan has host & port options (run `php artisan help serve` for more options).

Therefore, you have to run `php artisan serve --host="10.11.12.11"` to serve your application.